# Find text between two keywords using VIM Regex

Tags: regex, vim, regex-lookarounds, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am trying to configure syntax highlighting in Vim. Using regular expressions I am not able to find the character between two sequence of characters.

The sequence is:

```
facebook&sdk_version=7.2.3&appid=34428&language=en_AR&screen_height=1136&app_version=7.2.3&apple_idfa
```

An I would like to grab the part between for instance `"sdk_version="` and `"&appid="`. Meaning `7.2.3`

Any idea?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the skd version is going to come right before the appid? You're probably better off grabbing a number that comes after the attribute of interest: /sdk_version=(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/

Comment: What it is guaranteed is that after sdk_version= there will be a &

Comment: Is it that you want to capture the value between *each* `=` / `&` pair, not just the value of `sdk_version`?

Comment: Exactly, i just want the value in between. Using vim regex not regular

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
sdk_version=\zs\d\+\.\d\+\.\d\+
```

Everything before the `\zs` will be required to match, but won't be considered *part of* the match.

Then your actual match will be three numbers, separated with dots.

Another option would be grabbing everything after 'sdk_version=' until the next ampersand:

```
sdk_version=\zs[^&]*
```

Comment: The second one is perfect. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To match all the values:

```
=\zs[^&]\+\ze&
```

or

```
=\zs[^&]\+
```

(The first RE requires there to be a `&` after the last value, i.e. the last component must be a valueless attribute, as in your example.)

Both variants prohibit empty values: since the purpose was highlighting, I assumed that empty values weren't interesting. Substitute `*` for `\+` to allow them.